# Controlling gem install options with bundle

Tags: ruby

```
bundle install
```

where some gem that depends on libv8 is in the Gemfile (indirectly) leads to compile errors with libv8.

So, following advice, I did:

```
sudo gem install libv8 -v 3.16.14.11 -- --with-system-v8
```

and it succeeded (after brew install of libv8)

However, gem install keeps trying to do the install of libv8 without the --with-system-v8 option.

Can I explicitly put libv8 into the Gemfile with the option? I can't see where to put such an option in the spec for Gemfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8
```